# WebSphere MQ File Transfer Edition Web Gateway and windows (NTLM?) authentication

Tags: websphere-mq-fte

We are working with IBM MQ File Transfer Edition Web Gateway. We are managing(CRUD) file spaces through the RESTful endpoint like this -

```
http://172.99.9.99:9080/wmqfte/admin/
```

and using basic HTTP auth.
So, everething has been ok but now we need to make authentication through HTTPS and using windows tools like NTLM (client and server are in the same domain), because our security team told us that it's not safe to transfer credentials through the head of the HTTP request.

I've been reading documentation about "WebSphere MQ File Transfer Edition Web Gateway" and i've only found that

"You can create and delete file spaces and control the users that have access to individual file spaces.
The Web Gateway can be administered in the following ways:

```
By using the Web Gateway administrative console
By using the RESTful administration API and constructing HTTP requests manually
```

Please help me pointing into the some documentation or telling me whether it's possible or not. 
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

WebGateway runs under an application server environment like WebSphere Application Server. I believe the authentication mechanism you use to logon would apply to WebGateway also. Here is a link that may be of help.

http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wmqv7/v7r5/topic/com.ibm.wmqfte.doc/web_security_req.htm

Comment: Thanks for answering! I think you're right. But it takes a time to check and setup it. I'm busy with other tasks for now. I post here if I make it work in somehow suitable way.